# Can we have hard-coded roles in ASP.NET Identity?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I'm new to ASP.NET Identity, and am struggling with roles. My previous experience in in desktop apps (where we obviously couldn't use ASP.NET Identity, and mainly rolled our own roles), and we usually added an `enum` for the roles. This enabled us to refer to them unambiguously in code.

ASP.NET Identity seems to require roles stored in the database. My main issue with this is that we can't guarantee that everyone (all developers, the test and production databases) will have the same data in our databases. By using an `enum`, the data is hard-coded in the code, so no possibility of ambiguity.

A secondary (but still very important) issue is that roles seem to rely on you using hard-coded strings:

```cs
[Authorize(Roles = "SomeRole")]
public IActionResult SomeAction() => View();
```

This seems brittle. It's all too easy to mistype the role name, and what if we want to change the name? We'd have to hunt down every instance of the hard-coded string and change it.

To clarify, roles are being used to restrict access to certain areas of the web site. We will have a fixed set of roles, which will rarely change. If they do change, the code will need to change with them, so dynamic access to roles (eg via a CRUD section of the site) is pointless.

Can we do this? If not, how do we get around the issue of knowing how to refer to roles that may not exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid mistyping, you could try `const` instead of `enum`.

**RoleConst**

```cs
public class RoleConst
{
    public const string Admin = "Admin";
    public const string User = "User";
}
```

**Insert Role**

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        var host = CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build();
        using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
        {
            var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
            try
            {
                RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager = services.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
                if (roleManager.Roles.Count() == 0)
                {
                    //insert role
                    roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(RoleConst.Admin)).ConfigureAwait(true);
                    roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(RoleConst.User)).ConfigureAwait(true);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var logger = services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
                logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred while seeding the database.");
            }
        }

        host.Run();
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
}
```

**Use `Authorize` with `RoleConst`**

```cs
[Authorize(Roles = RoleConst.Admin)]
public IActionResult Privacy()
{
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Now that's clever! I didn't know you could create the roles with a fixed value. I'm not at my PC now, so can't try it yet, but will give it a go and see how it works. Thanks

Comment: @AvrohomYisroel What do you mean by "create the roles with a fixed value"?

Comment: I thought that roles were referred to by their ID, much like database rows when the primary key is Identity(1,1), which meant that different devs might have different IDs. I didn't realise you could refer to roles by name, so if we use a constant (like you showed), we avoid the problem.